# redirect to page dependant on roles

Tags: php, mysql

I redirect users dependant on role;

```
username  |  password  |  accessLevel
xxxxxx       xxxxxx       admin
xxxxxx       xxxxxx       member
xxxxxx       xxxxxx       none
```

I have the following check.php page;

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "index.php"
$_SESSION['myusername']= $myusername; 
$_SESSION['mypassword']= $mypassword;
$role = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 if($role['accessLevel'] == "admin"){
        header("location:index.php");
            exit();
      }
      elseif($role['accessLevel'] == "member"){
  header("location:tasks.php");
        exit();
     }

else {
echo "Error: Username, Password or Access Level incorrect! Go Home, you're Drunk!!!";
}

    }
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

This redirects the right role to the right pages, but if they type pages in the same directory they can also access other pages i dont want them to, i want to limit the "member" to certain pages and the "admin" to all pages, what do i need on the top of the pages to distinguish the 2 user roles?

i have the following on top of all my pages;

```
    <?php
session_start();
////if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
header("location:main_login.php");
}
```

can i change this to limit the page dependant on accessLevel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by assigning session name on the check_login.php page and checked isset on the pages i wanted to restrict for admin only.

i tried this previous but had syntax errors which i have now fixed after a coffee and fresh air.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple and i did that in almost all of my project,
What you have to do is,
ALTENATIVE 1.
 pass role into session too AS USERNAME, after successful login then at the top of the each page start session and check for permission.
forexample: index.php for admin

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if($_SESSION['accessLevel'] !== "admin"){ header("location:Adminlogin.php"); }
?>
 <!-- go whith your page -->
```

same to tasks.php for member

```
<?php  session_start();
```

if($role['accessLevel'] !== "member"){header("location:Memberlogin.php"); } ?>

ALTENATIVE 2.
Give different session id's for member and admin,

example: from the part of your code...

```
<?php 
  //fetch its role in DB then assign, like
  if($role['accessLevel'] == "admin"){

   $_SESSION['admin']=$role['username'];

    header("location:index.php");

  }
  elseif($role['accessLevel'] == "member"){
  $_SESSION['member']=$role['username'];
  header("location:tasks.php");

 }
```

then before  load full page firstt check the access like i did above
if for

```
$_SESSION['admin']
```

or

```
$_SESSION['member'].
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Your page ha s the following mistake, you have to fix them.

1. you pass password as clear text (md() is needed for encryption)

2.you store password into sessionvariable, what for? ( if user log in sucessfull we take his/her id into session for other use not checking  login always.

3.stripslashes,mysql_real_escape_string are not ecure enough for you to pass the password direct, Query by username then compar

Also there is NOTICE on your code.

1. try to avoid the use of * in sqlSting(query statments),
tey hinder perfomance.
select only field tha you have to use.

2. there is no need of using exit() where you place them, if...else enough

3.Instead of
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$myusername= mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);

you can have 

$myusername = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($myusername));
```